# Is it possible that !important only affects to one slot?

Tags: html, css, background-image

Is there a way to select the *slot* which the `!important` should use? I mean, if I have the following code:

```
.my_class {background-image: url(other_image1.png) !important;}
.my_class {background-image: url(image1.png), url(image2.png), url(image3.png);}
```

In this code, the background image of the element with the class `.my_class` is only the `other_image1.png` image beacause of the `!important`. But I also need to show `image2.png` and `image3.png`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `!important` applies to entire rules, not parts of them.

Comment: _nothing_ applies to parts of a single property.  multi-valued properties are all or nothing; they cannot partially cascade.